# How do I configure the vendor prefixes used by nib?

Tags: css, stylus, vendor-prefix

How can I tell [nib](http://visionmedia.github.io/nib/) not to generate prefixes for browsers I don't care to support?

Answer (score 5):

Just assign the variable `vendor-prefixes` before you `@import 'nib'` in your stylus source.  You can check the default values [in the source](https://github.com/visionmedia/nib/blob/master/lib/nib/config.styl#L11).

For example:

```
vendor-prefixes ?= webkit moz official
@import 'nib'
div
  background linear-gradient(red, blue)
```

yields:

```
div {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f00, #00f);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#f00, #00f);
  background: linear-gradient(#f00, #00f);
}
```